# Oracle Database creation with exitsting tables

Tags: oracle

I've database with 15 tables. Now due to development process  one column has to added to all the tables in the database. This changes should not affect the existing process because some other services are also consuming this database. So to accomplish it I thought of creating a new database. Is there are any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it should be enough to create a new schema ("user") and create the tables in that new schema. In Oracle, identically named tables can exist in several schemas.

```
CREATE USER xxx IDENTIFIED BY yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create another schema for development and import the table to new schema.Developer should use the development schema instead of production schema.you can also create new database and import from current database but it might be last option

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `alter table T add (COL varchar2(5));` ?

Of course dependend stored procedures or packages become invalid.
You can leave them alone, then the first call would return an exception and auto-recompile the called procedure. Or you can `alter procedure P compile;`.